# Vertical align of several elements in Nav Bar not working

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am attempting to create a nav bar which consists of 5 elements (4 regular swap image links and 1 larger logo in the center that spins on hover), however when I attempt to vertically align the the 4 smaller elements in the center (so that they are vertically in the middle of the larger logo) it does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

**CSS and HTML code**

```css
#navigation {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
  margin: 30px; }
li { display:inline;
font-family: advent-pro, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
position:relative;
float:left; 
padding-left:30;
padding-right:30;
}
.midnav {
  vertical-align: middle;}

  
#a  {display:inline;
  text-decoration:none;
   position:relative;}

#ul {list-style-type:none;}
```

```html
 
  <style>
    .panel {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;  
        position: relative;
        font-size: .8em;
        -webkit-perspective: 600px;
        -moz-perspective: 600px;}
    
    .panel .front {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 900;
        width: inherit;
        height: inherit;
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
        -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .panel.flip .front {
        z-index: 900;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    .panel .back {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 800;
        width: inherit;
        height: inherit;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 
        -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .panel.flip .back {
        z-index: 1000;
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);}
</style>

<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="midnav">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="blabla" width="70" height="70" id="Image1"   
   onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image1','','blabla.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="midnav">
      <a href="About.html">
        <img src="blabla" width="70" height="70" id="Image2" 
   onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image2','','blabla.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="hover panel">
        <div class="front">
          <div class="pad">
            <img src="blabla" width="150" height="150" alt="logo front" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="back">
          <div class="pad">
            <img src="blabla" width="150" height="150" alt="logo back" />

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="midnav">
      <a href="blabla.pdf" target="_blank"   
   onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image6','','blabla.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
        <img src="blabla.jpg" width="70" height="70" id="Image6">
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="midnav">
      <a href="blabla.pdf" target="_blank">
        <img src="blabla.jpg" width="70" height="70" id="Image3"  
       onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image3','','images/logos/Words/contactD.jpg',1)" 
       onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your problem but it is really unclear to me. Do you want to center all your images so they do not align to the left?

Comment: Hi, sorry about being unclear, basically the way it displays for me right now is that the elements are all inline but the smaller images (not the big spinning logo in the center) are aligned with the top of the big logo, so I am trying to get the smaller images to be placed so that vertically they appear to be aligned with the center of the big image. Does that help, if not I can explain further, thanks! :)

Comment: can you show your full css of navigation

Comment: It does help but what you are describing has nothing to do with your code. At this very moment your menu is one long vertical beam with every image below each other. Your images are not aligning horizontally...

Comment: Hi sorry I forgot to upload the css completely it should be displaying now the way it is on my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make **ul** display like **table** and its **small images** as its **cell** using following css:

```css
    #navigation {
      float: right;
      position: relative;
      left: -50px;
      margin: 30px;
    }
#navigation ul{
 display: table-row;
}
    .midnav {
    vertical-align: middle;
     display: table-cell;
          }
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="midnav">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="blabla" width="70" height="70" id="Image1" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image1','','blabla.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="midnav">
      <a href="About.html">
        <img src="blabla" width="70" height="70" id="Image2" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image2','','blabla.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="hover panel">
        <div class="front">
          <div class="pad">
            <img src="blabla" width="150" height="150" alt="logo front" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="back">
          <div class="pad">
            <img src="blabla" width="150" height="150" alt="logo back" />

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="midnav">
      <a href="blabla.pdf" target="_blank" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image6','','blabla.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
        <img src="blabla.jpg" width="70" height="70" id="Image6">
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="midnav">
      <a href="blabla.pdf" target="_blank">
        <img src="blabla.jpg" width="70" height="70" id="Image3" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image3','','images/logos/Words/contactD.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align:center` if you are trying to place the images vertically centered and horizontally centered with the logo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x5x2hqcz/)

```css
#navigation {
    text-align:center;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    left: -50px;
    margin: 30px;
}
.midnav {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li class="midnav"> <a href="index.html">
        <img src="blabla" width="70" height="70" id="Image1" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image1','','blabla.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
      </a>

        </li>
        <li class="midnav"> <a href="About.html">
        <img src="blabla" width="70" height="70" id="Image2" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image2','','blabla.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
      </a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="hover panel">
                <div class="front">
                    <div class="pad">
                        <img src="blabla" width="150" height="150" alt="logo front" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                    <div class="pad">
                        <img src="blabla" width="150" height="150" alt="logo back" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="midnav"> <a href="blabla.pdf" target="_blank" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image6','','blabla.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
        <img src="blabla.jpg" width="70" height="70" id="Image6">
      </a>

        </li>
        <li class="midnav"> <a href="blabla.pdf" target="_blank">
        <img src="blabla.jpg" width="70" height="70" id="Image3" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image3','','images/logos/Words/contactD.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
      </a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```